# How to check for data loaded with interval in android studio kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

i have an app in which a show data on a google maps (pins). Now i have a RecyclerView-adapter that manages the items and a viewModel that read the data from the database and then passes this to the recycler-adapter.
In my code i load the data and then start the fragment with the google maps on it. Now most of the time the data is loaded by the time the fragment is shown. But because the data-read from the database is async (LiveData) sometime it happens the loading in not done yet.
Now the adapater gets notified of the new data but my google maps is past the code point where is checks for data and then shows and empty map.
My first idea was to poll for the data several times with an interval. So i tried:

```
        Timer().schedule(object: TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                // check is data is loaded
                Log.i("Help", "counter $counter - status " + mAdapter.status.toString())
            }

        }, 2000)
```

i wrapped this i a while where i do this 5 times.
But when i look at the log is see honderds of entries and not just 5 so this is not good.
There are so other tricks i can try but fact is, it will be a sad bit of coding.
What i would like is that google maps updates the pins the same way a recyclesView gets updated when the corresponding adapter receives a notification.

My question: what is the propper way to do this?

**Update**
To answer the questions asked:
In the onMapReadyCallback i basicly read the data from the adapter and use that to draw the pins. i am i a split where both the loading of the map is an async action and also the loading of the data is async.

Comment: Well, this is the main idea behind the `LiveData` - to be able to observe it for changes and not guess when the data is there. How do you fill google maps with data?